# CakePHP 3.0 how to contain a left outer join

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Suppose that `Candidates` has one field named `Ratings`.
The association is optional.

I want all `Candidates` having a rating other than 0 or no rating at all
and to contain the ratings in the result.

I managed to get the right query for the first part by coding a left outer join like this:

```php
$this->Candidates
  ->find('all')
  ->leftJoin(
    ['Ratings' => 'ratings'],
    [
      'Ratings.candidate_id = Candidates.id',
      'Ratings.rating = 0',
    ],
    ['Ratings.rating' => 'integer'])
  ->where('Ratings.id IS NULL');
```

However I failed to get the rating *contained* within the result. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `contain()` to the query?

```
$this->Candidates
  ->find('all')
  ->contain('Ratings')
  ->leftJoin(
    ['Ratings' => 'ratings'],
    [
      'Ratings.candidate_id = Candidates.id',
      'Ratings.rating = 0',
    ],
    ['Ratings.rating' => 'integer'])
  ->where('Ratings.id IS NULL');
```

Comment: I did, but then the `left join` condition is overridden:
 `LEFT JOIN ratings Ratings ON (Ratings.candidate_id = Candidates.id AND Ratings.rating = 0)`
becomes
`LEFT JOIN ratings Ratings ON Candidates.id = (Ratings.candidate_id)`

Comment: What is the relationship between candidates and ratings?

Comment: Candidates hasOne Ratings and the relation is optional.